# Just edit one block of default writer using pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

Tags: lua, pandoc, writer

On my Odyssee understanding Pandoc Lua writers I just wanted to test the `pandoc.scaffolding.Writer` to alter the `Figure` Block.

I have the following MWE in Markdown:

```markdown
![caption to an image](counter_plot_new_periods.png)
```

and the following Lua writer:

```lua
Writer = pandoc.scaffolding.Writer

Writer.Block.Figure = function(fig)
   return '\\test\n' .. Writer.Blocks(fig.content) .. '\n\\test\n'
end

Writer.Pandoc = function (doc)
  return Writer.Blocks(doc.blocks)
end
```

The docs state that "`Writer.Pandoc` renders the document’s blocks." And [this website](http://chulsky.com/pandoc/) says that the `Pandoc` constructor represents the whole document.

But if I run the writer from the command line to convert the .txt file to Latex with

```bash
$ pandoc -t test-writer.lua ast-test.txt -o ast-test.tex
```

I get the error:

```bash
No render function for Block value 'Header';
define a function `Writer.Block.Header` that returns a string or Doc.
stack traceback:
    test-writer.lua:66: in function 'pandoc.scaffolding.Writer.Pandoc'
    while rendering Pandoc
```

So Pandoc asks me to define every Block element for the writer on my own (If I define a custom `Writer.Block.Header`, it asks me for `Image`, `Plain` or other missing Blocks).

Is it possible to use the `pandoc.scaffolding.Writer` to edit only one Block and let all others untouched so they are rendered using the default settings of the particular writer (in my case `latex`)?